# Getting apache to work with PHP for a REST server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, rest, httpd.conf

I'm trying to use the code provided in [this php REST tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-beginners-introduction-to-http-and-rest/) at the very top. The code is server.php and the apache config is apache.conf

Anyway, when I try to run the program I get a "broken link" error. However, if I simply echo "hello" it will display the echoed statement. I did some digging around in the comments and I think it may be the configuration of apache, but I'm not having any luck figuring it out.

The path I'm using for the server.php file is located at C:\xampp\htdocs\rest\server.php

I added the following to my httpd.conf and nothing changed.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/.* rest/server.php
```

Looking at some of the comments, someone suggested changing it to this, but it didn't work either

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* rest/server.php/$0 [L]
```

I'm not sure how to configure a .htaccess file (or even where it would go using xampp), but could that be a possibility?

**edit - Still isn't working and I made the following changes**

I changed this in httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride ALL 
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</Directory>
```

I made a .htaccess file and placed it in my htdocs folder (in xampp) with the following lines

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/.* rest/server.php
```

Comment: .htaccess is basically a file you drop into a directory, which contains apache config directives. In practical terms, it's very much like a `<Directory>` directive block in httpd.conf.

Comment: I tried putting those blocks of code (not both at the same time) in a .htaccess file and that didn't work either.

Comment: you may have to enable .htaccess support in apache, with an `AllowOverride` directive. by default they're not processed/honored, because they're parsed on EVERY request, which is bad on busy sites.

Comment: Hmm, still didn't work. I updated my post above.

Comment: Does anyone else have suggestions?